# Multiple and fixed values for a model on a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form for creating a `company` model, and now I must add which Social Networks they're present at. So that means they could, for instance, mark that they're using Facebook and Linkedin. How would you guys suggest I go about doing this reference? I was creating a Social_Network model and referencing it through a has_many association, but when it came to adding this to the form, I got confused.

Hope that was clear enough - and thanks for any help =]

Comment: This screencast might help http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

Use the [select_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag) with multiple: true

```
<%= form_for(@company) do|f|%>
    <%= f.select(:network_id, options_for_select(@networks), {}, {multiple: true, size: 10}) %>
<% end %>
```